# How to convert bug dump of string to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following string. How to convert it to a Python dictionary and json dictionary?

```
str1 = ('\n'
 'slot  1\n'
 '=======\n'
 '\n'
 '\n'
 'Flags: F - Fragment entry  E - Port Expansion\n'
 '       D - DSCP Expansion  M - ACL Expansion\n'
 '       T - Cross Feature Merge Expansion\n'
 '\n'
 '\n'
 'INSTANCE 0x0\n'
 '---------------\n'
 '\n'
 '  Tcam 1 resource usage:\n'
 '  ----------------------\n'
 '  Label_b = 0x8\n'
 '   Bank 0\n'
 '   ------\n'
 '     IPv4 Class\n'
 '       Policies: PBR(RM_OUT)  [Merged]\n'
 '       Netflow profile: 0\n'
 '       Netflow deny profile: 0\n'
 '       Entries: \n'
 '         [Index] Entry [Stats]\n'
 '         ---------------------\n'
 '  [041f:159c2:040b] prec 1 permit-routed ip 0.0.0.0/0 224.0.0.0/4  '
 '[12479340]\n'
 '  [0439:14bd0:0425] prec 1 redirect(0x20538)-routed tcp 98.125.94.75/32 eq '
 '8000 0.0.0.0/0  [0]\n'
 '  [043a:1db48:0426] prec 1 redirect(0x20538)-routed tcp 98.125.94.75/32 eq '
 '7066 0.0.0.0/0 flow-label 655360  [0]\n')
```

below is example expected output:

```
StrDict1 = {'INSTANCE': '0x0', 'TCAM': 'Tcam 1 Bank 0', 'Policies': 'RM_OUT', 'redirect(0x20534)': ['98.125.96.0/22', 'tcp 98.125.96.0/22 eq 8850', '98.125.96.0/22 eq 443'], 'redirect(0x20538)': ['tcp 98.125.96.0/22 range 8848 8849', '98.125.88.0/21 eq 8850']}
```

Output dictionary should put all IP/subnet entries for same redirect under same list. This is just an example. output could be big dictionary with 1000s of lines depending on data in string that needs to be converted to dictionary.

Comment: What's your desired output? I don't see an obvious way to convert it to a dict. Please [edit] to clarify. BTW, welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: First off, you need to determine which part would be considered a key and value, then you need to determine how to extract the key and value pairs. If there are duplicate keys, how would you want to handle it. You have to analyze the data first and figure out what makes sense for you. Then decide on dictionary and how you want to store it. Thats what I would do.  While I say that, have you tried anything or are you spreading a net to catch something here?

Comment: Thx. I've added expected output. new here.

Comment: @slowstack `98.125.96.0/22` doesn't occur in the input. Where is it coming from?

Answer (score 0):

For the start, you need some lexical parsing, i.e. create iterator that pics keywords and IP addresses and other parts from the text:

```
HEX_VALUE = 0
IP_VALUE = 1
...
def lex(text):
   for line in text:
      line = line.strip()
      if line == '':
          continue
      if <some regex>:
         yield 'INSTANCE',  'INSTANCE' # type of token and its value
         continue
      if < some other regex>:
          yield IP_VALUE, '10.0.0.1'
     # and so on
```

Then the approach for parsing this kind of data is to create "finite automata" that will implement syntax analysis. You start with some variable that is a state and give it initial value:

```
state = 'seek for INSTANCE'
```

and then loop over tokens:

```
result = dict()
for token, value in lex(str1):
    if state == 'seek for INSTANCE':
        if token != 'INSTANCE':
            continue # ignore everything before 'INSTANCE'
        state = 'GET INSTANCE VALUE'
        continue
    if state == 'GET INSTANCE VALUE':
       if token != HEX_VALUE:
           #some error
       result['INSTANCE'] = value
       state = 'WAIT for TCAM'
       continue
```

It is up to you where to put more "intelligence", to lexical analysis part or to syntax part.